# Getting a recursion procedure to work in a loop scenario (start A -> B, then B -> A indefinitely)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey StackOverflow community!

I've checked the other recursion questions but couldn't find one that helps me track a certain variable throughout recursion. Please let me know if there is such a question.

My goal for this task is to use recursion specifically, not do this iteratively.

## Task and Setting

I have the following simple nested dictionary that stores all friends of people inside a certain network:

```
network = {'Jessica' : {'connections' : ['Name1', 'Name3', 'etc']},
           'Name2' : {'connections' : ['Name3', 'Name1', 'etc']},
           'Name3' : {'connections' : ['Name4', 'Name2', 'etc']}}
```

My task is to find a path from 'Jessica' to 'Name4' and present it as a list:
['Jessica', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4']

I've identified the following cases that need to be accounted for:
1. When the 'target' is in the 'seed' - this one is done (easy)
2. When the 'target' is not connected to 'seed' in any way - this is not done
3. When the 'target' is 2 steps away - this one is done
4. When the 'target is >2 steps away - this is where I'm stuck.

## The Code

Here are the code and variables:
network - this is a link to my data structure, described above
user_A - this is the 'seed' person
user_B - this is the 'target' person we want to find connection to

```
def find_path(network, user_A, user_B):

    # Case #1. When 'target' is in 'seed'. 
    # Case #3. This is also the last step of a recursion call - we return the answer in the list format
    if (user_B in network[user_A]['connections']): 
        return [user_A, user_B]

    # The check below is useful during the seed stage to make sure both A and B are in the network
    if (user_A not in network or user_B not in network): # This is a global check only for the first input
        return None

    # If we haven't found a match -> proceed to the recursion
    else:
        path = [] # That's the start of our path
        path.append(user_A) # Append A to the Path

        # Then we want to go one layer deeper into the friends of seed page
        next_lvl_connections = network[user_A]['connections']
        for connection in next_lvl_connections:
            return path + find_path_to_friend(network, connection, user_B)

The code above would output a correct output if both Alexander and Jennie are connected through one node:
[Alexander, Person X, Jennier

BUT the code crashes if we fall into a trap when both first and next page in recursion have the same connections, i.e. we go from A to B from B to A indefinitely.

print (find_path_to_friend(network, 'Alexander', 'Jennie'))
```

What I need help with is:
-tracking the nodes recursion has already visited. 
-compare it to the current 'seed' page. If 'seed page in visited_pages, the code should select another seed page.
-finally, if the code ran through all possible pages and have not found a match, it should return None.

Any help and advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to pass the current path as parameter to your function, and when recursing, you must call the function with the whole path until now - so you shouldn't either have `path = []` before calling recursively. You will also need to check only the nodes that aren't already in your path in order to avoid loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will find all the paths between users and return list of path. If there is not path it will return empty array.

It only search path in one direction ie `find_path(network, "Jessica", "Name4")` will look for path from "Jessica" to "Name4" but not from "Name4" to "Jessica"

```py
network = {'Jessica' : {'connections' : ['Name1',  'Name3', 'etc']},
           "Name1": {"connections": ["jpt","Name2"]},
           'Name2' : {'connections' : ['Name3', 'Name1', 'etc']},
           'Name3' : {'connections' : ['Name4', 'Name2', 'etc']}}

def find_path(network, user_A, user_B, path_traversed=[]):

    ## add user_A to path_traversed in very 1st call
    if len(path_traversed)==0:
        path_traversed.append(user_A)

    if user_A not in network:
        return []

    ## if user_B is in connections of user_A return path traverse till now + user_B
    if user_B in network[user_A]['connections']:
        path_traversed.append(user_B)
        return [path_traversed]

    ##  if not, look if friend_of_A has connection with user_B.
    ## do this for friend_of_A who is in network and 
    ## recrusively until all connections are traversed
    paths_found=[]
    for friend_of_A in network[user_A]['connections']:
        if friend_of_A in network and friend_of_A not in path_traversed:
            copy_path = path_traversed.copy()
            copy_path.append(friend_of_A)
            path=find_path(network, friend_of_A, user_B, copy_path)
            if path != None:
                paths_found = paths_found + path

    return paths_found


find_path(network, "Jessica", "Name4")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the input!

It will take me some time to get my head around how this code works! Can't wait to implement it and test myself.